# HighCharts - show xaxis titles

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am working with highcharts, but first let me explain.
The graph needs these items / options
 - each bar should have its own width (done)
 - each bar should have its own color (done)
 - a line with the avarage level (done)

However, there is one thing I can't get working: On the xaxis is need the names of the bars (like here: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-rotated-labels).

I've tried different methods, and if I use method 1 I can't set custom bar widths, if I use method 2 I can't set the titles on the x-axis. Anybody an idea?

My code so far:

```
$(function () {
// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        title: {
            text: 'Kerntaken',
        },
        labels: {
            enabled: true,  
        },
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Gemiddeld niveau',
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
        plotLines: [{
            color: 'black',
            value: '2', // Insert your average here
            width: '1',
            zIndex: 5, // To not get stuck below the regular plot lines
            label: {
                text: 'gemiddeld niveau',
                align: 'right',
                y: 12,
                x: 0
            }
        }],
    },{
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
    },{
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        allowDecimals: false,
    },{
        title: {
            text: '',
        },
        opposite: true,
    }],
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<b>{point.y:.2f}</b><br/>',
    },

    series: [{
        name: "Kerntaken",
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: ['#c8173c', '#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [{
            name: "Adviseren",
            y: 3.2,
            drilldown: "Adviseren",
        }],
    }, {
        name: "Kerntaken",
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: ['#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
        pointWidth: 50,
        data: [{
            name: "Analyseren",
            y: 1.5,
            drilldown: "Analyseren",
        }]
    }, {
        name: "Kerntaken",
        colorByPoint: true,
        colors: ['#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
        pointWidth: 30,
        data: [{
            name: "Organiseren",
            y: 3.9,
            drilldown: "Organiseren",
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'CP niveau',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [2],
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: 'gemiddeld niveau<br>',
        },
    }],
});
```

My fiddle with my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/Mik3yZ/L181kpqt/2/

Comment: In your  code drilldown id there but no drilldown sereis ,Do you really need drilldown series  or you mistakenly placed drilldown?

Comment: i need drilldown, only removed it since it was not relevant for this question

Comment: I would use one of the answers below. Just one thing is missing `plotOptions.column.grouping = false`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xkjqtcq3/2/ ;)

Comment: Thanks Pawel, thats the solution! Want to create an answer for it so i can accept that, or shall i accept below answer? :-)

Comment: @PawełFus Thanks Pawel, I was looking for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to fill data with nulls, neither with zeros, but you can simply provide `x` index in the point. I'm not sure if that is really suitable for your use-case with drilldown (and categorized axis), but may be enough:

Example for data:

```
series: [{
    name: "Kerntaken",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#c8173c', '#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [{
        x: 0, // added x-position
        name: "Adviseren",
        y: 3.2,
        drilldown: "Adviseren",
    }],
}, {
    name: "Kerntaken",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 50,
    data: [{
        x: 1, // added x-position
        name: "Analyseren",
        y: 1.5,
        drilldown: "Analyseren",
    }]
}, {
    name: "Kerntaken",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 30,
    data: [{
        x: 2, // added x-position
        name: "Organiseren",
        y: 3.9,
        drilldown: "Organiseren",
    }]
}, {
    name: 'CP niveau',
    type: 'spline',
    data: [2],
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: 'gemiddeld niveau<br>',
    },
}],
```

Now, as I said before, disable grouping from columns:

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    grouping: false
  }
}
```

And working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xkjqtcq3/3/

**Extra note:**

You have a lot of extra commas in your code, just be aware it will cause errors in IE < 9.

Answer (score 1):

Hi, can you check if it's this that you want?

I changed your series data to this:

```
{
    name: "Apples",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#c8173c', '#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 20,
    data: [3.2, 0, 0],
}, {
    name: "Bananas",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#f2d38d', '#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 50,
    data: [0, 1.5, 0]
}, {
    name: "Oranges",
    colorByPoint: true,
    colors: ['#e2584d', '#6f2236', '#4e787a', '#867e97', '#000000'],
    pointWidth: 30,
    data: [0, 0, 3.9]
}
```

You were giving the `data` an object, but it's expecting an array. I set 0's in the values to balance the sets in the other columns.

In the first object `data` attribute, the first value is for the apples in the first column. If you change the second value you will get apples in the second column and so forth. In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/L181kpqt/3/) you have apples in all the columns.

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/L181kpqt/3/) for your answer.

Comment: thanks for this, i have indeed also tried it this way. The thing with this solution is the bars are not centered. The first bar is aligned left, the second in the middle and the third at the right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the series data format like this. Since you are using multiple series, you should have the mapping category values(here null) for each series to show the correcsponding  x-axis Labels.

```
  series: [{
        name: "Kerntaken",
        pointWidth: 20,
        data: [3.2,null,null]
    }, {
        name: "Kerntaken",
        pointWidth: 50,
        data: [null,1.5,null]
    }, {
        name: "Kerntaken",
        pointWidth: 30,
        data: [null,null,3.9]
    }]
```

Here is the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkjqtcq3/1/), Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Nimmy, the same as the above answer from Perdo: i have indeed also tried it this way. The thing with this solution is the bars are not centered. The first bar is aligned left, the second in the middle and the third at the right.